# Is there an equation that fits the sequence $1, 1, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{115}{192}, \frac{11}{20}, \frac{5887}{11520}, \ldots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence starts with the values:
$$1, 1, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{115}{192}, \frac{11}{20}, \frac{5887}{11520}, \frac{151}{315}, \frac{259723}{573440}, \frac{15619}{36288}, \frac{381773117}{928972800}, \frac{655177}{1663200}, ...$$

> Is there an algebraic formula $f(n)$ that fits these values?

They are closely approximated by the equation $\sqrt{\frac{6}{π n}}$ for large values of $n$, but it isn't exact and the approximation gets worse as $n$ gets small. Another good approximation is $\left(\frac{n - 1}{2}\right)! / \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!$, but again it isn't exact, and it completely misses the first two values.

The numbers are the peak values of the Probability Density Function (PDF) of an [Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) (IHD) of $n$ variables; that is, a probability distribution of the sum of $n$ independent, uniformly-distributed, random variables, whose values range from $0$ to $1$. The PDF is a piecewise polynomial function composed of $n$ sections of degree $n - 1$ which, combined, cover the interval from $0$ to $n$. The peak value occurs at $\frac{n}{2}$. However, the IHD PDF does not have an algebraic definition as far as I can find, so I can't just plug in $\frac{n}{2}$ and call it a day.

Comment: Your question asks for an exact formula $f(n)$, but it seems you are actually after an approximation?

Comment: The Central Limit Theorem suggests the peak density is about $\sqrt{\dfrac{6}{\pi \, n}}$.  For example, with $n=9$ this suggests about $0.4607$ rather than the actual $0.4529$

Comment: @angryavian No, I'd like an exact formula if it exists. All I've been able to do so far is approximate it.

Comment: @Henry that certainly is a good approximation, but I'd like an exact form if possible.

Answer (score 2):

My contribution will arrive lately, but your sequence also seems to be the values for $n \in \Bbb N^*$ of

$$A_n=\frac 1\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n dx$$

The resolution of this integral is well-known for n=1 ("Dirichlet integral") or n=2 (i.e. with complex integration, Laplace transform or "Feynman's trick"), but I'd be very curious to find a generalized study of this integral in respect to n and its result sequence (closed form or extension function of $A_n$, limit as $n\to\infty$, relaion with probability/PDF or other fields, ...), as I found this sequence by accident while playing on wolframalpha (and found your thread by googling the results), and I didn't found any accessible content describing it.

The numerators and denominators of the sequence are also listed on OEIS : respectively https://oeis.org/A002297 and https://oeis.org/A002298

Regards.

Comment: OEIS also gives us a sum for this sequence: $\frac1{2^{n-1} (n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} (-1)^k \binom nk (n-2k)^{n-1}$. The sequence [A261398](https://oeis.org/A261398) is also related.